# How do I create a reference point in git?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repository which includes submodules:

libs,
manager,
os,
application,

```
git clone git@git/products/xx_unknown.git project
cd project
git submodule init
git submodule update
git submodule foreach git checkout master
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

After above git commands the project now in a state of Build.

```
cd manager
```

did fews changes

```
git commit -am "it is working here"
```

But in a master branch of OS, libs, one of my team member did changes (100+ commits)

There are functional issues at latest changes. So, I want to share the refernce point ( local state of all submodules at my machine) with my colleague so he will checkout that reference point of all submodule for testing and verification.

I need something like Perforce lable command , which will create the reference point of all submodules at the current state.

Comment: Create a branch? (that is the only thing that can be checked out)

Comment: @crashmstr or a tag of course.

Comment: A git commit *does* contain revision information of all the submodules at that point.  If someone checks out the same commit and updates their submodules, they will have the same versions that were part of the commit.

Answer (score 0):

> I need something like Perforce lable command , which will create the reference point of all submodules at the current state.

This is what `git submodule` is for.
If you tag specific commits in xx_unknown.git, then when you init and update the submodules, they are checked out to the state they were in corresponding to the tag.

Assuming the following:

```
git clone git@git/products/xx_unknown.git project
cd project
git tag reference_point abcdef
git push origin --tags
```

You would then do:

```
git clone git@git/products/xx_unknown.git project
cd project
```

**`git checkout reference_point`**

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```